# What does JSON.stringify data look like in the url

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery, stringify

I use `JSON.stringify` to send jQuery arrays to `$_POST` data to a PHP file through an `.ajax()` call. The call works fine and the desired data is returned, but:

**If I was going to debug and type in variables manually, what does this data look like in url format?**

`http://domain.com/ajax.php?foo=1,2&bar=3,4` or something else?

**MY SOLUTION:**
URL is `http://domain.com/ajax.php?foo=[1,2]&bar=[3,4]`

Comment: when I `var_dump()` json_decoded array, I get a NULL result. I formatted the url as I have it in my question.

Comment: The URL in your question http://domain.com/ajax.php?foo=1,2&bar=3,4 is a GET Request.

Comment: He's saying to var_dump with the working input, just echo it out and you'll see the structure.

Comment: I know it's a GET request, I'm typing in the url of the file being called in the `.ajax()` request. The file returns JSON data, and I wanted to see how it's printing to check for a potential error.

Comment: your switching from post to get, so you should dump $_GET instead of $_POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using fiddler and use the Composer therefore you dont have to use separate code for debugging. You can also test what the result would look like by using the console in IE. Generally json.stringy turns your json into a string so it would look like

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to post the JSON data as a URL. You are mixing apples and pears. But you could do a few methods.

1) if the JSON is very simple you could actually do a url with the JSON data in it like this http://urdomain/ajax.php?data=[4,5,7] and use $_REQUEST['data'] instead of $_POST['data'] . but this could create more problems than it is worth.

2) best option is to use a browser plugin like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). You can do proper json posts and get the feedback.

3) or if u just want see what is happening you can just look at the browsers NET log in its development panel.